# Disable TCP ACK function for VoIP with TCP

Tags: tcp, voip, ack

Can I disable the ACK mechanism for TCP connections. In my country the DPI is activated for VoIP which blocks the remote end IP. (weather used with openvpn or IPsec or etc). However they are not monitoring TCP. the VoIP operates at TCP but the quality is very bad due to ACK function. I did try some DELACK but did not paid me off much. Could it be possible that I can disable the ACK in TCP protocol using some patch or some thing so I can operate VoIP with it. My servers are Linux CentOS based.

Answer (score 3):

No.

TCP without ACK isn't TCP.

If you were to hack the TCP stack somehow and prevent ACKs being sent then all kinds of things would stop working. You would need to adjust your version of TCP to the point where it simply wasn't TCP anymore. You would then need it running at both ends of the connection.

Comment: Thanks Len ! agreed with disabling ACK the other services will messed up too. Actually i did obfuscation of openvpn + UDP which did not worked and catch Up. can you please explain " You would need to adjust your version of TCP to the point where it simply wasn't TCP anymore ".

Or some thing like running OpenVPN with TCP minus ACK .....
Both the local & remote ends admin rights are with me.

Comment: Well, starting with the obvious issues: ACK is used signal that the data has arrived at the remote peer's TCP stack. Removing it would mean that the sending peer would never know if the data arrived; this would mean that it couldn't resend data that got lost and couldn't manage flow control. The protocol that was formerly TCP now isn't a reliable protocol and can't behave nicely with other data streams as it has no way to throttle itself.

Comment: @LenHolgate So basically, it turns into UDP?